# 700 °C insulating material used for a spacer

Tags: materials

I have a problem with finding a material that does not self ignite below 700 °C.

It is supposed to serve as a 5 mm spacer that is also serving as a best thermal insulation as possible. The spacer must be non-conductive to electrical current. Because the spacer must not scratch or shatter the glass it will be placed on, the spacer must be relatively soft as it must hold 10 kg of mass.

If no one knows about such a material, then I must completely rethink my solution.
There is additional problem regarding the "glueing" such material to iron based hot base.

Comment: Fiber glass should work fine.

Comment: Contact [Cotronics](https://www.cotronics.com/vo/cotr/) or look at their website. This is pretty much "what they do."

Comment: Pretty much most materials don't self-ignite below 700 °C.

Comment: Ceramics. (Fiber glass won't work well if the matrix is epoxy) You can even find machinable ceramics (MACOR) if you can't find the form you need. Soft layer may need to be fibre : if not glass fibre then something like Kaowool.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to machine it, Macor is a possibility 1.46 W/m-K. Good to about 1000°C.

There are also some types of mica-silicone that are barely within that range for intermittent use, but not for continuous exposure.

You can get commercial tubular spacers in Steatite good to 1200°C, but thermal conductivity is about double that of Macor.